# New Build: Various BSOD exactly 1:30 after boot every time, hardware?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, crash, hardware-failure, computer-building

Windows boots and I can login fine but it crashes shortly after every time (1:30 after Windows load). I’m convinced it’s a hardware issue but need some assistance debugging it further.

**One of the following 3 errors pops up exactly 1:30 after Windows is loaded:**

1. KMODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (wof.sys)
2. SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED (Wof.sys)
3. PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA

**Debugging attempts so far:**

1. Ran memtestx86 for four passes on both the memory sticks and each individually with no errors.
2. Removed the graphics card and loaded using integrated graphics (still crashed).
3. Booted in Windows safe mode (stable)
4. Refreshed Windows and booted in normal (crash at 1:30 every time)
5. Tried wiping the drive and reinstalling Windows (crashed during Windows installation)
6. Tried installing Ubuntu and running it from an USB, install and live runtime both crashed.

   - Does this mean the SSD is not to blame since Ubuntu crashed while running on an USB?

**Next Steps**

1. Test SSD: Swap the SSD for another HDD/SSD and try reinstalling Windows on it without crash.

   - If crash hook up first SSD to another computer, reinstall Windows and check stability.
2. Find some way to test CPU and motherboard?
3. Power supply issue maybe? (Used old PSU 850w, should be fine and shouldn’t crash when gpu is removed…)

**Additional Notes**

1. I used the same installation media (USB) on another computer without issue so it is not a corrupt installation. In addition to this I tried another installation USB with a different version of Windows 10 and had the same problem.
2. According to a benchmark I ran before the BSOD returned all of the devices were performing as expected other than the SSD, and RAM. The RAM I later found out was because I wasn’t utilizing the dual channel configuration, but the SSD I don’t have a reason for.

Has anyone had similar experiences?
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

[My build](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/coltonf93/saved/#view=9WZnTW):

- CPU: Intel Core i5-6600K 3.5GHz Quad-Core Processor
- CPU Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO 82.9 CFM Sleeve Bearing CPU Cooler
- Motherboard: MSI Z170A GAMING M5 ATX LGA1151 Motherboard
- Memory: G.Skill Ripjaws V Series 32GB (2 x 16GB) DDR4-2133 Memory
- Storage: Sandisk Ultra II 960GB 2.5" Solid State Drive
- Video Card: MSI GeForce GTX 1070 8GB Video Card
- Power Supply: EVGA SuperNOVA NEX 750W 80+ Gold Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply
- Monitor: 2 x Asus VP239H-P 23.0" 60Hz Monitor
- Keyboard: Logitech G510 Wired Gaming Keyboard
- Mouse: Razer DeathAdder Chroma Wired Optical Mouse
- Headphones: Razer BlackShark Headset

Comment: Sounds like you have narrowed it down to the SSD. I would do detailed troubleshooting there.